# c++ program breaks right after exiting for loop

Tags: c++

```cs
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    std::vector<int> answers(t);
    for (int i = 0, n, a; i < t; ++i) {
        int net = 0, sum = 0;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> input(n);
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> m(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> a;
            input[j] = a;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j += 2)
            sum += input[j];
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j) {
            m[j][j + 1] = input[j] - input[j + 1];
            if (j % 2 == 0)
                m[j][j + 1] *= -1;
            if (m[j][j + 1] > net)
                net = m[j][j + 1];
        }
        for (int j = 3; j < n; j += 2)
            for (int k = 0; k <= n - j; ++k) {
                m[k][j + k] = m[k][k + 1] + m[k + 2][j + k];
                if (m[k][j + k] > net)
                    net = m[k][j + k];
            }
        answers[i] = sum + net;
    }
    for (auto i : answers) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My code runs smoothly inside the main for loop. The moment I exit the for loop, my code breaks. I've tried debugging and I think it has something to do with deallocating the 2d vector "m". I've never encountered this issue and I think I've initialized "m" correctly.

Here's an input you can try

```
1
10
7 8 4 5 7 6 8 9 7 3
```

Comment: Even when coding for so-called "competition" or "judge" sites, please try to do so using good habits. Like well-commented code, descriptive variables names, adding empty lines to add paragraphs in the code, and skip that `sync_with_stdio` which is just plain [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). Making your code easier to read will make it easier to understand, and will make it easier for us to help you. Also tell us what problem it's supposed to solve, copy-paste it into your question, not only link to it.

Comment: In a loop where `k <= n - j`, the index `j + k` can therefore be `j + n - j`, _i.e._ `n` which is out of bounds. Therefore, _writing_ to `m[k][j + k]` is undefined behavior that may result in memory corruption, leading you to think there's a problem deallocating `m`. Likewise, it's also undefined behavior to _read_ from an out-of-bounds location.

Comment: `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);` - Why? Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

j + k was sometimes at least n, which meant that I was out of bounds